# Creating multiple models/controllers

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm still learning Codeigniter/PHP/Database/SQL.

Whenever i encounter new problems, i usually learn something to solve them that may/may not apply to my previous methods.

If they do apply to previous methods or if i make changes to my database design, i usually have to edit/update my CRUD methods relevant to the tables changed.

The problem lay there, since i write my methods as i need them and i don't follow any plan so they're all over the place.

It's not that its not solveable but its very hassle and it just saps away any anticipation i had towards improving my codes then i end up just doing other stuff(procrastinating), its a very vicious cycle, whenever i try to get into it, i end up procrastinating then days pass by then weeks.

I also want to implement thin controller/fat model idea ive read online. Up to now, this is also a part of the problem. I'm trying to solve them all right now but i have a question/doubt before i can truly do it.

I separated my controller into two. 1. needs authentication 2. no authentication.

For now, i have my main controller with methods that needs a user logged in. 
for example, user/story dashboard, submitting stories. etc.

The other one is my pages controller, i put there the methods that don't need any user authentication. Like viewing homepage, viewing story profile, reading a chapter, viewing user profile. etc.

In my models, i have separated them into two. account_model and story_model. Any method related to account like registration,logging in etc. and story like publishing story,fetching story data, etc.

My problem with that is that there are some methods that fall into a gray area. or some methods that i would like to group but get separated.

For example: I have a review system(my previous question), users can review other users(author) who have published their stories, stories and chapters.

In my models, the review_author method would go into account model, the review_story and review_chapter would go into story model.

Is it correct for me to just make a review_model and put them all there? 
In line of that thought, can i also make separate models for separate groups of methods for example, Pagination model for any method related to pagination(user/story). dashboard model for any method related to my user/story dashboard.

The essence of my question is that i want to be as efficient as possible(of my level of knowledge) so that whenever i get far into my project i don't lose enthusiasm if i have to make changes because of the headache inducing wall of codes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question is way to broad. Please read 
[**How to Ask a good question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and find out how to use this site
[**taking the tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Ahh, i've googled my question online but the answers vary from different levels of knowledge. since people have different preferences. 

For me, i just decided to go with what i am comfortable with regardless if its correct or not.(no choice). 

Just gonna create models per group of methods.

Comment: Please please read the how to ask section, basically, if your question is about organization and structure chances are its too broad. But if I were you I would totally separate the models into functions (not php functions but like what they accomplish). So yes, a separate model for reviewing. If models get way too long, over 500-700 lines... consider separating it even further. Make a models subfolder called reviewing and have, for example, `review_author_model` `review_story_model` .etc.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for debugging. This question is well written, but not for this site. I think with a few tweaks it could be on topic for our sister site [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or if you have some example code that demonstrates the decision you're trying to make, [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).